# How to add text to the end of the result of a command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I have a command that I use on a script and it is working well. I need to append some text to the result of that command.

Command:

```
ssh target_server "/home/directory/somescript.sh" | tail -1
```

I want to add some text on the result of the command above.

**Sample result:**

```
This is the original result
```

**Sample Desired result:**

```
This is the original result - target_server
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipe it to [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

```
ssh target_server "/home/directory/somescript.sh" | tail -1 | sed 's/$/ - target server/'
```

---

The syntax is `s/regexp/replacement/flags`.

- `s` invokes the substitute command.
- `/` is the delimiter. You may choose another character for the delimiter.
- `$` is in the regular expression slot. `$` matches the end of the line.
- `- target server` is the text which replaces what was matched by the regular expression slot.

If the replacement text contained `/` (for example, `- target 01/10`), you would either escape it or choose another delimiter:

```
sed 's/$/ - target 01\/10/'
sed 's|$| - target 01/10|'
```

Comment: if it's multiline result, this is appended to all lines. Use `'$s/$/ - target server/'` for last line only.

Comment: @pLumo it can't be a multiline result, there's a `tail -1` there.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: Right, I meant it more like a general note.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

## Using bash loops

```
cmd | while read line; do echo "$line - target_server"; done
```

This only uses bash builtins thus fewer processes will be created/destroyed.

## Using bash function

You can also create a simple bash function. Defining it as below:

```
function postpend() { 
    while read line; do 
        echo "${line}${1}"; # Insert text parameter after the line.
    done;
}
```

Then you would call it:

```
cmd | postpend " - target_server"
```

## Using AWK

```
command | awk 'END{print $0 " - target_server"}'
```

## Using sed

```
command | tail -1 | sed 's/$/ - target server/'
```

I hope this helps.